# Java - ignore exception and continue

Tags: java

For my Java application, I am creating an instance of a user information object and populating it with a service that I don't control the source for.

The code looks like this:

```
// username given as parameter
UserInfo ui = new UserInfo();
try {
    DirectoryUser du = LDAPService.findUser(username);
    if (du!=null) {
       ui.setUserInfo(du.getUserInfo());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Whatever
}
```

If `LDAPService.findUser()` can't locate a user, it will throw a `NullPointerException` and grind the rest of my application to a stop. It's okay if the user information isn't populated, so I want to be able to continue without causing everything else to start throwing exceptions.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Ignoring exceptions is bad practice!

Comment: Doesn't your code do this? As long as `// Whatever` does nothing, execution will continue normally after the try/catch block.

Comment: what's the problem? If `findUser` throws an exception, it is caught in the `catch` you've allready written. It will not stop anythign?

Comment: Why would it throw a NullPointerException, since you only call getUserInfo if du is not null?

Comment: @Крысa - In general, an ignored exception should be a warning flag. In this case, OP made a point of saying that it's ok if the user information isn't populated.

Comment: @JBNizet - I was assuming that the NPE was thrown by `findUser`. But if indeed it returns `null`, then you're right--there's no opportunity for a NPE in this code.

Comment: If it's thrown by findUser, then either username is null and shouldn't be, or the findUser method has a bug.

Comment: findUser has a bug, but I can't do anything about it since I don't control the source for the LDAPService class. Hence the question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've upvoted [Amir Afghani's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8436360/400127), which seems to be the only one as of yet that actually answers the question.

But I would have written it like this instead:

```
UserInfo ui = new UserInfo();

DirectoryUser du = null;
try {
    du = LDAPService.findUser(username);
} catch (NullPointerException npe) {
    // It's fine if findUser throws a NPE
}
if (du != null) {
   ui.setUserInfo(du.getUserInfo());
}
```

Of course, it depends on whether or not you want to catch NPEs from the `ui.setUserInfo()`  and `du.getUserInfo()` calls.

Comment: I'll mark yours as answer. It looks like all I needed was a tighter try/catch block.

Comment: I have up-voted your answer because a) you're right, and b) you've explicitly called me out.

Comment: I would add since we don't necessarily want to catch and ignore ALL NullPointerExceptions, one could further look at the details of the NPE (getCause, getMessage, getLocalizedMessage, getStackTrace) and if it doesn't match a very specific and narrow criteria, re-throw it. But then, I just noticed my comment is about 7 years after the fact.

Answer (score 21):

You could catch the `NullPointerException` explicitly and ignore it - though its generally not recommended.  You should *not*, however, ignore all exceptions as you're currently doing.

```
UserInfo ui = new UserInfo();
try {
    DirectoryUser du = LDAPService.findUser(username);
    if (du!=null) {
       ui.setUserInfo(du.getUserInfo());
    }
} catch (NullPointerException npe) {
    // Lulz @ your NPE
    Logger.log("No user info for " +username+ ", will find some way to cope");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are already doing it in your code.  Run this example below.  The catch will "handle" the exception, and you can move forward, assuming whatever you caught and handled did not break code down the road which you did not anticipate.

```
 try{
      throw new Exception();
 }catch (Exception ex){
   ex.printStackTrace();
 }
 System.out.println("Made it!");
```

However, you should always handle an exception properly.  You can get yourself into some pretty messy situations and write difficult to maintain code by "ignoring" exceptions.  You should only do this if you are actually handling whatever went wrong with the exception to the point that it really does not affect the rest of the program.

Answer (score 2):

It's generally considered a bad idea to ignore exceptions. Usually, if it's appropriate, you want to either notify the user of the issue (if they would care) or at the very least, log the exception, or print the stack trace to the console.

However, if that's truly not necessary (you're the one making the decision) then no, there's no other way to ignore an exception that forces you to catch it. The only revision, in that case, that I would suggest is explicitly listing the the class of the Exceptions you're ignoring, and some comment as to **why** you're ignoring them, rather than simply ignoring **any** exception, as you've done in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually ignoring exception in your code. But I suggest you to reconsider.

Here is a quote from [Coding Crimes: Ignoring Exceptions](http://java.dzone.com/articles/coding-crimes-ignoring)

> For a start, the exception should be logged at the very least,  not
>   just written out to the console.  Also, in most cases,  the exception
>   should be thrown back to the caller for them to deal with.  If it
>   doesn't need to be thrown back to the caller,  then the exception
>   should be handled. And some comments would be nice too.
>
> The usual excuse for this type of code is *"I didn't have time"*,  but
>   there is a ripple effect when code is left in this state.  Chances are
>   that most of this type of code will  never get out in the final
>   production. Code reviews or static analysis tools  should catch this
>   error pattern. But that's no excuse,  all this does is add time to the
>   maintainance and debugging of the software.

Even if you are ignoring it I suggest you to use specific exception names instead of superclass name. ie., Use `NullPointerException` instead of `Exception` in your `catch` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a try - catch block around the line you want to have ignored.

Like in the example code of yours. If you just continue your code below the closing bracket of the catch block everythings fine.

Answer (score 0):

LDAPService should contain method like `LDAPService.isExists(String userName)` use it to prevent NPE to be thrown. If is not - this could be a workaround, but use Logging to post some warning..

Comment: If there i one way to know that user is not present in LDAP is to get NPE - it's ok to ignore it, but by the way you should log it at INFO/DEBUG layer

Answer (score 0):

Printing the STACK trace, logging it or send message to the user, are very bad ways to process the exceptions. Does any one can describe solutions to fix the exception in proper steps then can trying the broken instruction again?